# Add a header to a tab delimited file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, cat

I'd like to add a header to a tab-delimited file but I am not sure how to do it in one line in linux.

Let us say my file is:

```
roger\t18\tcolumbia\tnew york\n
albert\t21\tdartmouth\tnew london\n
etc...
```

and now I'd like to add a header that says:

```
name\tage\tuniversity\tcity
```

How would I do that in one line in linux?  I am ok with awk, sed, cat, etc. not familiar at all with perl though.

Comment: Are you asking how to put the line of text / header at the beginning of the file?

Comment: yes.  I can see you already replied. thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There isn't a "prepend" operator like the "append" operator `>>`, but you can write the header to a temp-file, copy your file's contents into the temp-file after that, and move it back:

```
echo -e "name\tage\tuniversity\tcity" | cat - yourfile > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out yourfile
```

Comment: This is a good technique, but you need `cat - yourfile` if cat is going to look at its input.  (That is, you must give `-` explicitly as an argument to cat.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell You're absolutely right - typo on my part; thank you for catching that for me!

Answer (score 9):

```
$ { printf 'name\tage\tuniversity\tcity\n'; cat orig-file; } > new-file
```

Or

```
$ printf '1\ni\nname\tage\tuniversity\tcity\n.\nw\n' | ed -s orig-file
```

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would go with `nano -w file.txt` ;-) (i.e. just use a text editor, doesn't have to be nano of course)

But if you wanted to do this in a non-interactive environment for some reason, you can use `cat` for all sorts of concatenations:

```
echo $'name\tage\tuniversity\tcity' | cat - file.txt > file2.txt
```

will prepend the header and put the output in `file2.txt`. If you want to overwrite the original file you can do it with

```
echo $'name\tage\tuniversity\tcity' | cat - file.txt > file2.txt; mv file{2,}.txt
```

Or you could use `sed` as follows:

```
sed -i $'1 i\\\nname\tage\tuniversity\tcity' file.txt
```

Note that I'm using `$'...'` quoting to allow me to use `\t` to represent tab and `\n` to represent newline (among other substitutions; see the bash man page for more). In this type of quoted string, `\\` represents a literal backslash. So the program passed to sed is actually

```
1 i\
name    age     university      city
```

Comment: an additional Q, how would I add a variable name into echo $'name\tage\tuniversity\tcity' | cat - file.txt > file2.txt.  I.e., echo $'${shellvar}\t${shellvar2}\tuniversity\tcity' | cat - file.txt > file2.txt.  I tried like that and did not work at all.

Comment: Shell variables are only expanded within double quotes, so you will have to mix quoting styles. Fortunately bash allows you to run different kinds of quoted strings right up against each other and it will join them accordingly. `"${shellvar}"$'\t'"${shellvar2}"$'\tuniversity\tcity'`

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -i -lne 'if($.==1){print "newline\n$_"}else{print}' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a file with the header content:

```
$ cat >header
name^Iage^Iuniversity^Icity (return)
^D
```

(where `^I` is the tab key)

Then prepend it to the data

```
$ cat header myfile >newfile
$ mv newfile myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat <(head -1 theFileWithHeader) theFileWithoutHeader > newfile;
mv newfile theFileWithoutHeader;
```

Answer (score 0):

Customary `awk` answer.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { print "name\tage\tuniversity\tcity" } { print }' yourfile > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` no need of temp file

```
sed -i "s#^#name\tage\tuniversity\tcity#g#"
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file1.txt
roger\t18\tcolumbia\tnew york\n
albert\t21\tdartmouth\tnew london\n
etc...
$ sed -i "s#^#name\tage\tuniversity\tcity#g#" file1.txt $ cat file1.txt
name    age     university      cityroger\t18\tcolumbia\tnew york\n
name    age     university      cityalbert\t21\tdartmouth\tnew london\n
name    age     university      cityetc...
$
```