# How to insert headers into a tab delimited file?

Tags: python

So I have the following datasource ("/" represents tab delimited locales), and I want to get it into a JSON format. The data have no headers, and I'd like to be able to insert one for the name, the degree, the area (CEP), the phone number, the email, and the url. Not sure if this will be possible for the first column which contains multiple variables.

Any recommendations on how to insert headers and then parse the first column? The csv module has the "has_header" function, but I want to insert a header.

```
Rxxxx G. Axxxx M.A.T., xxx    561-7x0-xxx     rxxxxx@xxxx.com    www.txxxx.com
Pxxxx D. Axxxx Ed.M.
xxxxx D. xxxx Ed.M.           413-xxx-xxxx    xxxx@gmail.com     www.pxxxxt.com
xxxxx xxxx xxxxx M.S.
xxx xxx xxxxxx M.S.
xxxxxx R. xxxxx M.B.A.
xxxxxx xxxxxx M.A.Ed., CEP
```

[This is a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902497/unix-linux-add-a-header-to-a-tab-delimited-file)

And I've tried:

```
echo $'name\ phone\ email\ url' | cat - IECA_supplement_output.txt > ieca_supp_output.txt
```

but this doesn't work. It merely gives me 'name\ phone...' at the tope and then the data right beneath. The header is not separated by tab.s

Comment: So the earlier version of this question had a comment that pointed out that this isn't a CSV, in the sense that newline characters aren't escaped and each line doesn't represent a single row, also the `/` doesn't appear to separate the phone number and the email address in line 3.  Do you have control over the incoming data?

Comment: Right...um...I'm not sure why the lines don't represent rows. I've tried to space the first row to show that it's tab delimited. I manually inserted the "/" to represent where TextWrangler marks off the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that delimiter is really what you think. You can check this by opening the file using openoffice or writing a python function to detect the delimiter using regular expressions (re module). Also make sure that lines are ending with "/n" or windows style (additional r).

Header is nothing more than the first line. So open the file in python, read all lines. Prepend the header string (separated by **/t for tab delimiter** ) to the first line. Write the lines back to the file. 
That's it.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in python you can try and read each line (fixing the data as you go) and then write a fixed Tab Separated Value file with headers like so:

```
import csv

rows = []
with open('rawdata.txt') as f:
    row = ['']
    for line in f.readlines():
        data = line.rstrip().split('\t')
        if len(data) > 1:
            row[0] += data[0]
            row.extend(data[1:])
            rows.append(row)
            row = ['']
        else:
            row[0] += data[0] + ' '

with open('data.csv', 'wb') as o:
    file_writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter='\t')
    file_writer.writerow(['Name','Phone','EMail','URL'])
    for row in rows:
        file_writer.writerow(row)
```

This takes the following data file as it's input:

rawdata.txt:

```
Rxxxx G. Axxxx M.A.T., xxx  561-7x0-xxx rxxxxx@xxxx.com www.txxxx.com
Pxxxx D. Axxxx Ed.M.
xxxxx D. xxxx Ed.M. 413-xxx-xxxx    xxxx@gmail.com  www.pxxxxt.com
xxxxx xxxx xxxxx M.S.
xxx xxx xxxxxx M.S.
xxxxxx R. xxxxx M.B.A.
xxxxxx xxxxxx M.A.Ed., CEP  415-xxx-xxxx    xxx@compuserve.net  www.hxxxxxl.com
```

This code assumes that the last line of the file fits the ideal format of "name, phone number, email, and web site", otherwise the last "incomplete" rows will be silently dropped.  As it reads each line it looks to see if there are enough columns to satisfy a valid row.  if there aren't it appends the name column to a variable and keeps reading, if there it takes the name column and combines it with the contact information and appends it to an array called `rows`.  Once it is done reading the input, it uses Pythons `csv` module to write the data after appending a header row.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an elegant, programming method to accomplish this, but the method I used was to open the .txt file in excel using 'tab' as the separator. After I opened the file, I just typed in the column headers into the first row. Piece of cake! :)