# Insert a pipe separated header to a large txt file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have pipe separated large file(s) that has more 10,000,000 lines. All of these files are missing header and only the first split has the header. I want insert the header line for the rest of the files.

I tried following:

`sed -i '1 i \user_id|name|age|transactions' file.txt`

but this didn't work. What is the most efficient way to insert a header line for large file.

[Similar question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902497/add-a-header-to-a-tab-delimited-file), unfortunately solution didn't work. It could be due to `sed` structure of understanding pipe separation might be different.

Comment: there will be no "fast" way to do this. Any change like this will require opening a new file, writing the header, then copying all the data from old file into new file. (and, once you're sure things are working as needed, you'll probably want to delete the old file). But at ~1GB per minute to write files on a reasonable system, it shouldn't take that long. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '1s/.*/user_id|name|age|transactions\n&/' file.txt
```